# Strict Solution of a Differential Equation

Tags: differential

I know what the solution of a differential equation means, but I am confused that what do we mean by Strict Solution of a differential Equation.

Comment: Can you give us context, such as a specific question or exercise where this appears?

Comment: It's impossible to answer without further context. Maybe it is related to particular solutions, maybe it's a sub-solution strictly smaller than the solution (or a super-solution strictly greater than the solution), who knows...

Comment: The definition of the strict solution is given in the book "Analytic semigroups and optimal regularity in parabolic problems" by Alessandra Lunardi.